# where do I send my ajax calls

Tags: plugins, ajax

Fighting to create an ajax request. I've been reading couple of articles but still I can't get my plugin to send and recive ajax datas.

first init the js

```
    function ajax_load_scripts() {
        // load our jquery file that sends the $.post request
        wp_enqueue_script( "ajax-calls", plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/assets/js/ajax_calls.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

        // make the ajaxurl var available to the above script
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-calls', 'the_ajax_script', 
                array( 'ajaxurl' =>   plugin_dir_url('my_plugin.php') ,
                       '_ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'my_ajax_nonce' )
                  ) );
    }
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'ajax_load_scripts');
```

than trying to catch posted data in my plugins entry file

```
function tipps_processing_function(){
    check_ajax_referer('my_ajax_nonce');

    if ($_POST['results']){
        $token = '393a9276ae329e00b3739d2e76e52f3b';
        $tips = json_encode($_POST['results']);
        $save = new Tipspiel();
        $save->save_tips($token, $tips);
            var_dump($_POST['results']);
        return 'OK';
    }
    //do stuff here
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_tipps', 'text_ajax_process_request');
```

my js

```
$j("form#tiepspiel").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // this disables the submit button so the user stays on the page            
        var str = $j(this).serialize();
       //alert(decodeURIComponent(str));
        if ($j('ul#sortables li').size() > 10){

            $j( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
                    height: 140,
                    modal: true
                });
            return;
        }
        var data = {
                action: 'add_tipps',
                tips: str,
                _ajax_nonce: the_ajax_script._ajax_nonce

            };

        $j.post(the_ajax_script.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
            //$j.cookie("tipspiel", "competitor", { expires: 1 });
           $j('form#tiepspiel').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                // Animation complete.
              });
        });              
    });
```

but I don't see  my varibales dumped

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browsers script console? Is `$j` your alias for `jQuery`?

Comment: firebug shows no errors. alert box is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use the WordPress enviorment and functions in your ajax processing funciton then you need to post/get your AJAX request to admin-ajax.php, So change

```
'ajaxurl' =>   plugin_dir_url('my_plugin.php')
```

to

```
 'ajaxurl' =>   admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this, which will work for not-logged-in visitors:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_tipps', 'text_ajax_process_request');
```

But if you don't have this too, you won't trigger the call for logged-in users (which I presume you are):

```
add_action('wp_ajax_add_tipps', 'text_ajax_process_request');
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your JS isn't including the 'action' parameter, or it isn't set to `add_tipps`. Here's an example of the JS you can use, [from the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action: 'add_tipps',
        whatever: 1234
    };
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
</script>
```